# Android Listview: After searching items do not re-appear

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a little app listing up some items called "Spielort". Searching for them through an EditText works great, but when removing the search-string or just removing letters from it, the whole list of the items does not reappear. Does anyone know why and may offer some advice on how to edit my code?

SpielortAdapter.java

```
package fasde.android.distanceapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.LayoutRes;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SpielortAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Spielort> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Spielort> spielortList;
    private List<Spielort> filteredList;
    private List<Spielort> allDataList;
    private SpielortFilter filter;

    public SpielortAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes ArrayList<Spielort> spielortList) {
        super(context, 0, spielortList);
        this.context = context;
        this.spielortList = spielortList;
        this.allDataList = spielortList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItem = convertView;
        if (listItem == null) {
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        Spielort ort = spielortList.get(position);

        TextView spielort = listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView_ort);
        spielort.setText("\t" + ort.getSpielort());

        TextView km = listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView_km);
        km.setText(Integer.toString(ort.getDistanz()) + "km");

        TextView kosten = listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView_kosten);
        kosten.setText(ort.getKosten().toString() + "€");

        TextView kreis = listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView_kreis);
        kreis.setText(ort.getKreis().getName());

        return listItem;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new SpielortFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    private class SpielortFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Spielort ort : spielortList) {
                    if (ort.getSpielort().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                        filteredList.add(ort);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filteredList.size();
                results.values = filteredList;
            } else {
                results.values = allDataList;
                results.count = allDataList.size();

            }
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, @NotNull FilterResults results) {
            spielortList = (ArrayList<Spielort>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package fasde.android.distanceapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    SpielortAdapter spielortAdapter;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.spielort_list);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        List<String> setup = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Spielort> spielorts = new ArrayList<>();

        Map<String, Spielort> vereine = new TreeMap<>();

        for (Spielort ort : Spielort.gottaListEmAll()) {
            vereine.put(ort.getSpielort(), ort);
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Spielort> entry : vereine.entrySet()) {
            setup.add(entry.getValue().toString());
            spielorts.add(entry.getValue());
        }


        spielortAdapter = new SpielortAdapter(this, spielorts);

        listView.setAdapter(spielortAdapter);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // Nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                MainActivity.this.spielortAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });


    }


}
```

Edit: Removed unnecessary lines from publishResults()

Edit2: Errorlog

```
E/: [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: fasde.android.distanceapp, PID: 9529
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at fasde.android.distanceapp.SpielortAdapter.getView(SpielortAdapter.java:42)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2451)
        at android.widget.HwAbsListView.obtainView(HwAbsListView.java:935)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1426)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1333)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:401)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:726)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:847)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2954)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1753)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2041)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1636)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7946)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1092)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:812)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9529 SIG: 9
Process 9529 terminated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove below 3 lines from `publishResults` method

```
        clear();
        for (Spielort ort : spielortList) {
            add(ort);
        }
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

Update your `performFiltering()`

```
 constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
 FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
 filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Spielort ort : allDataList) {
                if (ort.getSpielort().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                    filteredList.add(ort);
                }
            }
            results.count = filteredList.size();
            results.values = filteredList;
```

Comment: Now the app crashes on searching

Comment: Errorlog added.

Comment: yeah checked what you returns in your get count method?

Comment: I did not override it, so I guess it is int from ArrayAdapters getCount()

Comment: override it and return  spielortList.size()

Comment: Okay now everytime the search is empty, the whole list comes back, which is great, thank you, but is it possible to reset the search already when removing chars from the search?

Comment: yes, you have to update your logic at `performFiltering()`

Comment: How exactly do I have to do that?